# Pass request header and request body in kubernetes nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am passing the authorization header in ingress yaml file

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni......"
```

but getting the error

> 2021/03/01 09:23:58 [emerg] 947#947: too long parameter, probably
> missing terminating """ character in /tmp/nginx-cfg445808174:586

I want to pass the request payload as well to the auth-url
what is the right way to pass the authorization header and request body?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the authorization header

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
```

Comment: Can I pass the curl command like this : 
curl -k -X POST "https://hw1.yourdomain" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..."  -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"operationId\":\"query\",\"scope\":\"region\"}"

Is this the right way to pass the authorization header and request payload to backend via ingress controller

Comment: Yes you can give it try.

Comment: you can also cehck example : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/basic

Comment: No is is not passing the header and the body..getting 500 internal server error

Comment: Give me min checking for same i did few time back.

Comment: which version of nginx ingress are you running ?

Comment: It is the latest version  us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0

Comment: I checked debugging the application locally , authorization header is coming but the POST request body is getting dropped by nginx

Comment: ok got it........i had one demo ready for post passing body let me check

Comment: did you tried with increasing body limit in proxy ?

Comment: what is the setting to do that and what should be the size to try

Comment: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"